# using Switch and strings java

Tags: java

I've heard that you can use switch on strings, but Im not getting it to work. ToDo would in this case be a user input String, but my compiler tells me "int cannot be converted into String". 
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
class Comands {
  public Comands () {} 

  public void doSomething (String toDo){

    while (!(toDo.equals("quit"))) {
      switch (toDo) {
        case 1: toDo.equals("right");
        System.out.println("go right");
        break;

        case 2: toDo.equals("left");
        System.out.println("go left");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `case "right": System.out.println("go right"); break; case "left":...`

Comment: See also the Java Tutorial on strings in switch statements (at the bottom of the page): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 switch (toDo) {
    case "right":
    System.out.println("go right");
    break;

    case "left":
    System.out.println("go left");
    break;
  }
```

Note: Only in Java SE 7 and later, you can use a String object in the switch statement's expression.

More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to do ignoreCase somehow?

Comment: @stian You need to use if statements if you want to ignore case.

Comment: @stian It's not possible to use `ignoreCase`, but you can do `switch (toDo.toLowerCase())` so that you know your string will be lower case.

Answer (score 3):

Like @Hovercraft Full Of Eels mentioned, you are comparing your string with integer in `case 1:`, this should contain a string like this:

```
...
case "left":
    // sysout();
    break;
case "right":
    // sysout();
    break;
...
```